# Excel for Mac 2016 - Save As CSV - Bad Line Endings

Tags: excel, macos, csv, line-endings

I have some CSV import code that is failing to import files exported by Excel for Mac 2016.

The CSV import code can handle {CR}, {LF}, or {CR}{LF} line endings perfectly, but Excel for Mac is exporting files with completely broken line endings.

For example, if I start with a worksheet like this:

```
Foo|Bar
---+---
123|456
```

I would expect it to look like this when exported to CSV:

```
Foo,Bar{CR}123,456
```

(I don't care which line ending is used - it can be {CR}, {LF}, or {CR}{LF}, and my CSV import code will handle it correctly).

However, here is how Excel for Mac 2016 is actually exporting it:

```
Foo,Bar{CR}{CR}{LF}123,456
```

If I try to save it as "Windows CSV", then it actually adds an extra column, but doesn't fix the line endings at all:

```
Foo,Bar,{CR}{CR}{LF}123,456,
```

Is there a specific set of options I should be using when exporting to CSV?

EDIT: I should add that if I export to CSV from Excel for Mac 2016, and then immediately open the file in Excel for Windows 2016, it is imported with an extra row between each row of data, like this:

```
Foo|Bar
---+---
   |   
---+---
123|456
```

So it's not just a problem with my CSV import code - even Excel for Windows won't read an Excel for Mac CSV file properly.

Comment: I am unable to replicate this with Excel 2016 or 2011 on a mac os 10.11.5

Comment: I can confirm this issue is present using Excel Version 16.9 (180116) on Mac OS X Version 10.12.6. This is odd, given the comment by @dawg above, considering I'm on a later OS version than he is. I am identical behavior in all respects to what djhayman noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I believe that I may have found the answer.

I didn't mention it earlier, because it never occurred to me that it might be causing this issue, but after exporting each CSV file I was emailing it to a Windows PC to test it out.

And apparently, Mac Mail corrupts line endings in attached CSV files!

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2235362

I am still seeing issues when these files are uploaded directly and processed with my CSV import code, so I will have to see if Safari is corrupting CSV files too.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add a bit more detail in terms of what I'm seeing on Mac OS X 10.12.6 using Excel Version 16.9 for Mac.

- When I export a CSV from `R` on my Mac, all lines end in {LF}.
- When I open the exported CSV in MS Excel and do nothing but re-save the file by clicking Ctrl+S, the resulting line endings are changed to {CR}{LF}. So Excel is adding {CR} to the line endings. This happens to still read OK, because {CR}{LF} is the standard Windows line ending.
- When I use Mac Mail to email the CSV file exported from `R` as an attachment, all lines in the received attachment end in {CR}{LF}. So Mac Mail is adding {CR} to the line endings. Similar to how Excel adds {CR} characters, this still reads OK; the program will just think it came from Windows because of the line endings.
- When I use Mac Mail to email the CSV file I've saved from Excel as an attachment, all lines in the received attachment end in {CR}{CR}{LF}. This adds an extra carriage return to the CSV when viewed on Windows. When viewed in Notepad, the extra lines are suppressed, but when viewed in Excel, there are extra blank lines inserted between each original line because of the added {CR}.

This is odd behavior and has the potential to break downstream software that consumes CSV files that were exported from Excel on a Mac and then emailed to users. I don't currently know of any workaround for this other than avoiding the use of Mac Mail to send CSV attachments.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Excel export function, copy data to text editor, eg. TextEdit on Mac.
(New window, Format -> Make Plain Text)
Then copy the data column separator (the gap between the values of adjacent columns) from TextEdit window to 'Find' dialog box, 
and type "," (without quotes) in 'Replace with' box.
Click 'Replace All' and you'll have your Excel data separated by commas in the TextEdit window.
Save file with .csv extension.

It should open in both Mac & Windows versions of MS Excel.

Tested on Mac OSX 10.6.8 & Win 10.